# Unable to highlight a selected row in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

This question has been asked a lot of times, and I am posting this question after reading around 20 posts and trying their various solutions in my code.

I have used a selector, and I have also defined choice mode of the `ListView` as `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`. But nothing works. Here is my xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_key" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the java code for above file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    TextView textView;

    String array[] = new String[] { "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl",
            "mno", "pqr" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, array);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.setSelected(true);
                String clicked = array[position];
                textView.setText("You clicked " + clicked);

            }
        });

    }
```

And here is the `bg_key.xml` file stored in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/pressed_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/default_color"/>

</selector>
```

The selected row still does not stay highlighted once it has been clicked. It is highlighted momentarily, but then it reverts back to the original color.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about using listselector ?!

```
<listView
android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector"/>
```